# Getting redundant pageview events with GA4 and NextJS

Tags: google-analytics, next.js, single-page-application, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to transition a NextJS app to GA4.

Initial page loads send events as expected, but subsequent pages (visited by clicking a link generated by the Next’s Link component) will log pageview events twice. Other events fire once, as expected.

In other words, if I go to Page A, then click a link to Page B, Page A the realtime events will show one visit to Page A but two visits to Page B.

Can't tell if this is a GA4 bug, a NextJS bug, or a problem with my implementation.

This behavior is not observed in our traditional GA setup, and it is observed even when stripping all of the existing GA analytics (employed via [React-GA](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga)), and it is observed in and out of dev mode.

The GA4 tag is loaded on each page by including the following in a common component:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-xxxxxxxx" />
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
  __html: `window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'G-xxxxxxxx');`,
  }}
/>
```

Comment: How is the client-side transition page view handled? The snippet you provided will handle the initial page load reporting, but there must be additional GA code to handle client-side navigations.

Comment: Previously, a custom function would invoke ReactGA to send a pageview with the current path. Buy my understanding is that GA4 detects changes to the history and will automatically create pageview events with every change … and that's my so far been my experience, but it’s doing it _twice_.

Comment: Are you using the GA debugger chrome extension and do you see the pageview fire twice in the console?

Under the `Web Stream>Enhanced Measurement>Pageviews>Advanced` settings in GA, what is your setting for 'page changes based on browser history'? I presume it's checked as it sounds like this is what you want?

It sounds as if the script above may be running on the client-side navigation, and the GA setting is set to true so it's also recording due to the `history` change. You could add a `console.log` to check this? You shouldn't get the log on the client side page change.

Comment: Perhaps try including the regular GA include as part of the server rendered response (don't use dangerouslySet...), keep the GA option 'true' to track history changes as pageviews. That way, the server-rendered pageview is recorded by the script running when the app shell loads, and then GA automatically tracks the history changes for client side page changes.

Answer (score 6):

I spent half a day on this (getting double `page_view` events with Gatsby and `gatsby-plugin-google-gtag`) and I'm pretty sure that the solution to your problem is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/66318326/365238

Basically GA4 introduces something called "Enhanced measurement" which tracks more stuff than GA used to. This setting is on by default and annoyingly overrides `gtag('config', { send_page_view: false })`. I'm not sure if this should be submitted to Google as a bug or we should simply stop trying to handle history changes manually and let GA do its magic.

This behavior can be disabled by going to Admin in GA, then to your property, choosing Data Streams, then choosing the stream that your app is using and disabling "Enhanced measurement" altogether:

[image: Screenshot of disabled Enhanced measurement]

Or by disabling tracking browser history in particular (click on the cog icon showing up when "Enhanced measurement" is on to see this):

[image: Screenshot of disabled browser history events]